# Inconsistencies in R rasterize polygons, packages raster and sf

Tags: r, rasterization, sf

I was trying to calculate species richness from IUCN distribution data in R, and I decided to check my results with two different methods, both of which rely on `rasterize` function from the raster package.

1. The simplest method consists in counting the number of species in each grid cell by using the `length` function in `rasterize` (it is actually described in `rasterize` help as an example to be used to calculate richness).
2. A slightly more complex method consist in rasterizing each species polygon into presence-absence rasters, and then summing all rasters to obtain a species richness raster.

However, I ran into minor inconsistencies in the results, and I am not able to figure out why.

I paste below the code I used for these two methods. [The dataset I used can be downloaded from the IUCN website here, download the **Tailed amphibians dataset (25MB)**.](https://www.iucnredlist.org/resources/spatial-data-download) *The IUCN requires an account to download the data, I am sorry about that but I cannot find another way to make a reproducible example of this dataset (and I am not allowed to redistribute it).*

Note that in this dataset, there can be multiple polygons for each species. Species names are in the column `binomial` of the IUCN dataset.

### Data preparation

```
# Packages
library(raster)
library(sf)

# Reading the polygons
iucn_sf <- st_read("./data/IUCN data/CAUDATA.shp")
# Some data filtering
iucn_sf <- iucn_sf[which(iucn_sf$presence == 1), ]
iucn_sf <- iucn_sf[which(iucn_sf$origin == 1), ]
iucn_sf$binomial <- droplevels(iucn_sf$binomial)

# Creating a raster at the desired resolution
r <- raster(nrows=180, ncols=360, xmn=-180, xmx=180, ymn=-90, ymx=90, 
            crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0", 
            resolution = 1, vals=NULL)
```

## Method 1: rasterize species polygons into richness raster with `length`

This method is described [in the `rasterize` documentation.](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/2.8-4/topics/rasterize)

```
a <- rasterize(iucn_sf, 
               r,
               field = "binomial",
               fun = function (x, ...) length(unique(na.omit(x))))
plot(a)
```

[image: Results of method 1]

The maximum richness with method 1 is 26.

## Method 2: rasterize each species into a presence-absence raster and then calculate the sum

```
pa.stack <- stack()
for(sp in levels(iucn_sf$binomial))
{
 # We rasterize the polygons of the current species into values of 1
 pa.stack <- addLayer(pa.stack,
                      rasterize(iucn_sf[iucn_sf$binomial == sp, ],
                                r, 
                                field = "binomial", 
                                fun = function(x, ...) 1))
}
# After the loop, we sum all presences to obtain the species richness
b <- sum(pa.stack, na.rm = T)
plot(b)
```

[image: Results of method 2]
The maximum richness with method 2 is 25.

## Differences between methods 1 and 2:

```
plot(a - b)
```

[image: Differences between method 1 and 2]

You can see that most of the results are the same, except for a few pixels where there can be a difference of 1 or 2 species. I do not understand where this difference comes from (is this a mistake in my code or a difference in the procedure?), which is why I turn to the wider community to seek advice.

I used R version 3.5.2, packages sf version 0.7-2 and raster version 2.8-4.

Comment: I've got your first example to run, but the second one references `cur.distrib` which you don't define. Not sure if this is the problem (maybe `cur.distrib` isn't quite the same as `iucn_sf`) but am stuck with that at the moment.

Comment: Oops sorry, I made a modification on my script while writing the message and forgot to report it here. It is corrected.

Comment: Now I get `Error in .polygonsToRaster(x, y, field = field, fun = fun, background = background,  :   when rasterizing multiple fields you must use "fun=first" or "fun=last"` in the `rasterize` for method 2... Same `raster` version.

Comment: Damn again, my bad. I corrected it.

Comment: Its all working and I can reproduce your differences now. Explanation might take a bit longer...

Comment: But if you want to investigate you might note that there's no difference if you subset `iucn_sf` to "Plethodon" spp only. I did this as a test so that things would run quicker and `a` and `b` are identical in that case. Really need to write these methods as functions for easier testing now, maybe its one species being a bit weird...

Comment: I decided to test method 1 on all species independently, (i.e. I applied method 1 in the loop of method 2), and in the end I did obtain the same result as method 2. There seems to be something wrong with method 1 on multiple species...

Comment: I did run the code family by family, and I had inconsistencies in multiple families. Maybe I should report this to the devs of raster, as I am not sure this is an expected behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you very much for reporting this. I have looked at this in detail, and in this case, method 2 produced the correct answer, whereas method 1 did not. This was related to polygons with holes and the order in which they were rasterized. I have fixed this in `raster` version 2.8-14